# Add item to listbox directly or use databinding?

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, windows-phone-8

Windows phone project.

I used a lot databinding before, currently I'm maintaining an old projrect. What make me struggling is that there's basicly no databinding when using Listbox control or something like that, instead they just add items as ListboxItem to Listbox directly.
I know this is another approach to present a list of items, and I'm curious about what's the difference between use databinding and add items to Listbox directly.